# How to select an attribute that contains an @-sign (at-sign)

Tags: xml, select, xpath

Given this xml:

```
<results>
    <result version="@2.15" url="some url"/>
    <result version="2.14" url="some url"/>
</results>
```

How do I select the element containing version="@2.15"? I have trouble figuring out how to put the @-sign in the XPath.

Thanks in advance,
Erik

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a detailed explanation then a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath selects the desired `result` element:

```
/results/result[@version='@2.15']
```

**Note**: There is no need to "escape" a literal `@`.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I select the element containing
>   version="@2.15"? I have trouble
>   figuring out how to put the @-sign in
>   the XPath.

**In XPath this is straightforward**: any string *literal* must be surrounded by a pair of quotes or apostrophes.

Thus:

```
@x
```

specifies an attribute named `x`

but:

```
'@x'
```

is just a string literal, containing the characters `'@'` and `'x'`

**Solution**:

Use:

```
/*/*[@version='@2.15']
```

This selects every element that is a child of the top element of the document and that has a `version` attribute with value the string `"@2.15"`